# Java "Space Invaders" cause "NULL exception"

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I can't fix my problem with loading images of aliens to my main program.

Here's the code of *Monster* :

```
 package classes;

public class Monster extends Actor {

    protected int enemySpeed;

    public Monster(Stage stage) 
    {
        super(stage);
        setSpriteName("0.png");
    }

    public void act() 
    {
        x+=enemySpeed;
        if (x < 0 || x > Stage.windowWidth)
            enemySpeed = -enemySpeed;
    }
    public int getVx()
    { 
        return enemySpeed; 
    }
    public void setVx(int i) 
    {
        enemySpeed = i; 
    }
}
```

---

Here is code of Actor ( it's main class to create images ) :

```
    package classes;

import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class Actor {
    protected int x,y;
    protected int width, height;
    protected String spriteName;
    protected Stage stage;
    protected SpriteCache spriteCache;
    private BufferedImage IMG;

    public Actor(Stage stage)
    {
        this.stage = stage;
        spriteCache = stage.getSpriteCache();
    }

    public void paint(Graphics2D g)
    {
        g.drawImage( spriteCache.getSprite(spriteName), x,y, stage );
    }

    public int getX() 
    { 
        return x;
    }
    public void setX(int i) 
    { 
        x = i; 
    }
    public int getY() 
    {
        return y; 
    }
    public void setY(int i)
    { 
        y = i; 
    }
    public String getSpriteName() 
    {
        return spriteName; 
    }
    public void setSpriteName(String string) 
    {
        spriteName = string;
        IMG = spriteCache.getSprite(spriteName);
        /*
        BufferedImage image = spriteCache.getSprite(spriteName);
        height = image.getHeight();
        width = image.getWidth();
        */
    }
    public int getHeight() 
    { 
        return height; 
    }
    public int getWidth() 
    {
        return width;
    }
    public void setHeight(int i)
    {
        height = i; 
    }
    public void setWidth(int i)
    {
        width = i; 
    }
    public void act() 
    {

    }
}
```

---

Last but not least code of SpriteCache where i load my images.

```
package classes;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.HashMap;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class SpriteCache 
{
    public HashMap<String, BufferedImage> sprites;

    public SpriteCache() 
    {
        sprites = new HashMap<String, BufferedImage>();
    }


    private BufferedImage loadImage(String sciezka) 
    {
        URL url=null;
        try 
        {
            url = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("0.png");
            return ImageIO.read(url);
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            System.out.println("Przy otwieraniu " + sciezka +" jako " + url);
            System.out.println("Wystapil blad : "+e.getClass().getName()+" "+e.getMessage());
            System.exit(0);
            return null;
        }
    }
    public BufferedImage getSprite(String sciezka) {
        BufferedImage img = (BufferedImage)sprites.get("0.png");
        if (img == null)
        {
            img = loadImage("0.png");
            sprites.put(sciezka,img);
        }
        return img;
    }
}
```

---

After all i get error :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at classes.Actor.setSpriteName(Actor.java:48)
    at classes.Monster.<init>(Monster.java:10)
    at Main.initWorld(Main.java:116)
    at Main.game(Main.java:99)
    at Main$1.run(Main.java:50)
```

I try to use everything and i don't know what is going on. 
I got all classes in 'class' folder and all images in 'img' folder.

Here's the MAIN class :

```
import java.awt.Canvas;


public class Main extends Canvas implements Stage {

    private JFrame frame;
    //wysokosc szerokosc
    private int windowWidth = 800;
    private int windowHeight = 600;

    //Buffor stretegi - odświeżanie ekranu ( ucieczka od migania ) 
    public BufferStrategy strategy;

    private SpriteCache spriteCache;
    private ArrayList actors;
    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Main window = new Main();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                    window.game();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public Main() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() 
    {       
        //główne okno
        frame = new JFrame("Wojna z Alienami by Dawid Raźny!");
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, windowWidth, windowHeight);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() 
        {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        //panel w którym będą rysowane obiekty i grafiki
        JPanel panel = (JPanel)frame.getContentPane();
        setBounds(0,0,windowWidth,windowHeight);
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(windowWidth,windowHeight));
        panel.setLayout(null);
        panel.add(this);


        //potrzebne elementy BufforStrategy
        createBufferStrategy(1);
        strategy = getBufferStrategy();
        requestFocus();

    }//konstruktor 


    public void game() {
        initWorld();
        while (isVisible()) 
        {
            updateWorld();
            paintWorld();
            try 
            {
                Thread.sleep(Stage.Speed);
            } 
            catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        }
    }

    public void initWorld() {
        actors = new ArrayList();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Monster m = new Monster(this);
            m.setX( (int)(Math.random()*Stage.windowWidth) );
            m.setY( i*20 );
            m.setVx( (int)(Math.random()*3)+1 );
            actors.add(m);
        }
    }
    public void paintWorld() {
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D)strategy.getDrawGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillRect(0,0,getWidth(),getHeight());
        for (int i = 0; i < actors.size(); i++) 
        {
            Actor m = (Actor)actors.get(i);
            m.paint(g);
        }
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        strategy.show();
    }

    public void updateWorld() {
        for (int i = 0; i < actors.size(); i++) 
        {
            Actor m = (Actor)actors.get(i);
            m.act();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public SpriteCache getSpriteCache() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

STAGE CLASS :

```
    package classes;

import java.awt.image.ImageObserver;

public interface Stage extends ImageObserver 
{
    public static final int windowWidth = 800;
    public static final int windowHeight = 600;
    public static final int Speed = 10;
    public SpriteCache getSpriteCache();
}
```

Comment: `spriteCache` is probably null

Comment: I know it! But i am asking why!!

Comment: You should try to narrow down where the problem could be. We only want the _relevant_ code, not all of it.

Answer (score 2):

Given your stacktrace the stage object is null when calling `spriteCache.getSprite(spriteName);`

Which means that the `Monster` you're creating in your main class is receiving a null `SpriteCache` instance.

In your `Main` class the `SpriteCache` is never instantiated so its value is `null` which leads to a `NullPointerException`.

Somewhere you need: `SpriteCache sc = new SpriteCache()` and use this instance to create your monsters. For example in your `Main` class you might want to change the attribute `SpriteCache` to `static SpriteCache sc = new SpriteCache();` and return it in the method `getSpriteCache` which would need to be static too.

Comment: I add it to my last post! :)

Comment: Ehh... still doesn't work. I didn't use SpriteCache in Main becouse it's not necessary.

Comment: Ok I guess you forgot a file that declares the `Stage` class ? Since you defined a method `getSpriteCache` in the class `Main` with the `@Override` method it will be called instead of the method with the same name from the class `Stage` hence return `null`. Remove this method from the `Main` class and you will get the instance returned by the class `Stage` instead which is probably what you want.

Comment: Actually i have Stage class and i add her code in my first post so you can check it. I delete it from main class and i still have the same problem. I'm getting tired of it...

Comment: @Raźnyy the method `getSpriteCache` does nothing in the `Stage` class and returns `null` in the `Main` class. One of them needs to return an actual instance of `SpriteCache` otherwise you'll end up with the same error. Somewhere in your code you should instantiate a new `SpriteCache` and use it.

Comment: Hm.. ok. Any ideas how to do it?

Comment: OK!!!!!!
I see my mistake ! 
Java automaticly create method 

    public SpriteCache getSpriteCache() {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      return null;
     }

and i didn't see it.*FACEPALM*

Thanks guys and sorry for problem! :))

Comment: @Raźnyy cool if you've seen where the problem is and remember that you probably want to _always_ get the same instance of `SpriteCache` ;)

Answer (score 2):

The error states that somewhere in `Actor.setSpriteName`, you are trying to dereference a null pointer. The only suspect line is `IMG = spriteCache.getSprite(spriteName);`, which suggests that `spriteCache` is null at the time of this line's execution. Since this is initialized with the line `spriteCache = stage.getSpriteCache()` (in `Actor`), it would seem that `getSpriteCache` is returning a null object. I hope that was easy to follow...